# Typing the relationship between items in an array

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

I want to create a function that takes an array of functions, where each item in the array is executed in sequence and the result is passed to the next item along with some other data. Here is an example of what I want to be able to do:

```
callExample([
  (stuff) => 123,
  (stuff, previousResult) => previousResult ** 2,
  (stuff, previousResult) => String(previousResult)
])
```

I want to be able to type this so I know what the type of `previousResult` is and to type the return of `callExample` to be the return type of the last function in the array.

I realise that something like

```
type Example<A, B, C> = ([
  (stuff: unknown) => A,
  (stuff: unknown, previous: A) => B,
  (stuff: unknown, previous: B) => C,
]) => C
```

works for a known number of elements, but is there a way to type the relationship itself and support a dynamic number of items?

Comment: how `stuff` should be typed?

Comment: I'd like it to be able to be anything for example it could be a number of milliseconds since `callExample` was called

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6GAEN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: okay, will write the answer when I get a chance

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tuple type along with the rest operator `...`

```
type MyArguments<A, B> = [
  (stuff: unknown) => A, // First element
  ...((stuff: unknown, previous: A) => B)[] // All other elements
]
```

`MyArguments` would then be a variable-length tuple type where the first element type is `(stuff: unknown) => A`, and the rest of the elements' types are `(stuff: unknown, previous: A) => B)`

Then your `Example` type would be:

```
type Example<C> = (args: MyArguments) => C
```

More info in the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types)

Comment: But this solution won't support different return types and previous values as expected. what if one of them returns number, the other one string, and some other returns boolean?

Comment: @wonderflame True, but you lose all the benefits of TypeScript by supporting types that aren't known at build time. It's better to just use either a union, or disable typing with `any`

Comment: I'm not sure If I understood your point, but what is the benefit of a union, where you can easily make a mistake? Please check my approach that I left in the comment under the question

Comment: @Ahmouse the return type of each item in the array would be known at build time. However different calls of `callExample` would have different arrays. So the idea is that when writing the array, I should be able to tell what arguments the functions will have

Comment: @ScottPage I see. From what I know, however, TypeScript won't be able to provide useful type checking on that array if all the items have different arguments/returns. It wouldn't know what methods or fields the array elements have, and thus can't validate method/property usage or provide auto complete. The only way it could could provide benefit over regular JS is if every element of the array can be inferred at build time and the array never changes, in which case just initializing the array with all the elements (which implicitly types it) would be a no-brainer.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm:

- Let `T` be an array of functions
- Get the first element of `T` and retrieve the type for the `stuff` and return type of the first function
- Call recursive type on the rest of the `T`

  - Let `Func` be the first element in the rest of `T`
  - Add to the `Result` array a function that accepts `stuff` with the defined type and the previous value, which is the return type of the previous function
  - Update the previous value to return type of the `Func`
  - If `T` is empty return the `Result`
- Spread the result with the first element to get the full array.

Implementation:

```
type UnknownFunc = (...args: any[]) => any;

type _ChainFunctions<
  T,
  FirstArgument,
  PrevTo,
  Result extends readonly unknown[] = readonly [],
> = T extends readonly [infer Func extends UnknownFunc, ...infer Rest]
  ? _ChainFunctions<
      Rest,
      FirstArgument,
      ReturnType<Func>,
      readonly [
        ...Result,
        (stuff: FirstArgument, previousResult: PrevTo) => ReturnType<Func>,
      ]
    >
  : Result;

type ChainFunctions<T extends readonly UnknownFunc[]> = T extends readonly [
  infer First extends UnknownFunc,
  ...infer Rest,
]
  ? readonly [
      First,
      ..._ChainFunctions<Rest, Parameters<First>[0], ReturnType<First>>,
    ]
  : T;
```

We are retrieving the elements of the function array using [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) keyword.

To get the type of `stuff` we use built-in [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) utility type

Usage:

```
const func = <T extends readonly UnknownFunc[]>(arg: ChainFunctions<T>) => {};
```

We will need to use [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to prevent the compiler from widening the type of the input array. Const assertion will turn the array to `readonly`, which is the reason why we have `readonly` everywhere:

```
func([
  (stuff: number) => 123,
  (stuff: number, previousResult: number) => previousResult ** 2,
  (stuff: number, previousResult: number) => String(previousResult),
] as const);

func([
  (stuff: number) => 123,
  (stuff: number, previousResult: string) => previousResult ** 2, // expected error
  (stuff: number, previousResult: number) => String(previousResult),
] as const);

func([
  (stuff: number) => 123,
  (stuff: string, previousResult: number) => previousResult ** 2, // expected error
  (stuff: number, previousResult: number) => String(previousResult),
] as const);
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgazgewO5wGIFc4GMoC8UAFAHTkCGATgOYDOAXFBXCANoC6AlIQHzOsA3AFgAUGNCQoAfQDCACwoBLTDlzAlyOHQA8YqFAAqAGn1QMSqnWABBWlgC2EOMFOiDABSoQAboeRuBgBKEHRYADbAUBAAHsDOACZ0UN4UCVrhIFA4SGhwnIQpEGkZWZxu-ESG0XGJyanpcJlQbCoAZhBU5mo18XBJsIgo6Nh4xlDkpO2dUCHWHGYA-DIKyqp4Glq6ZgbBoa47uxZWtvZOLoG7e8BYVHCG4BA6o7i8l1cNpS2HV5NzEQd3FddsRrFg2m0mMdrHYaI5nK4oGBvD5NFg6P9IkwvL5-DwCPwQjc7g9IM81G8flAFkCDLwzExMcAROJRJJoKsVC9NtodNVYn0Bp8mll4LkRmpOJUjL06kUSiLvkDpl1oVEBXKxcN1rhLpMVbN9m4aQZlsLmmwqWr3rtJnJFFy1DzdHNER5qBQnPErM9LNZeGwAAwccZE273R6+k68Sm06kMowssS4LZRNo9Ih82X9erFRrNLV5F5S4jUGhMTk65183j4-gAbwAvknROm8MRLUDQTcIUw4I4AEadOtQACMACYAMyXbvgyFQfsOIdUcbI3xojGhAF9wfDvhIlEbplQABUJ6g45nYN7C93K4P6+Q6KZO6Xe4JUAAysAqCoaMQ11RJ9NzCSIuGNZhkhTbRgC4Fs21wDszFnG9F2XEcJ2nZDr3nNDOlXQ9gJfKBrF-OAaBHQCjy3SJT3PS8oAAekYmpIHUCAEmiKgqGQKhsJ7XC7wIx9nxo4BX3Q-dvzI-8qKIsTwLEDhIKgaDrDgsQxAQpCuxwiT334TCrwEphSL-YSgNE0DxNvN8qEowirIBOiL3GZjWIgdjOM6Hi+N0kzbOXCzqOs-T7Kkn8-wAxyQIBRTRGUigoNTDTRCAA)